# Is checking `Future` state by `get(0, TimeUnit.Microseconds)` a good idea?

Tags: java, concurrency, executorservice, future

I'm having a `Future` and I want to find out what is its state. What I had in mind is a code like:

```
try {
    // Is that a good idea? Counting on exceptions looks weird.
    future.get(0, TimeUnit.MICROSECONDS);
    this.status = DONE;
} catch (InterruptedException e) {
    Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
    throw Throwables.propagate(e);
} catch (ExecutionException e) {
    this.status = FAILED;
} catch (TimeoutException e) {
    this.status = RUNNING;
} catch (CancellationException e) {
    this.status = CANCELED;
}
```

Looks like `FutureTask` will try hold a lock, and if it can get the lock will check `Future`'s state. So it seems like a good idea.

Are there pitfalls I'm missing here?

Comment: What's wrong with isDone() and isCancelled(), I don't think that reinventing them is good idea - you should avoid catching the exceptions when it's not needed.

Comment: Off-topic – but have you considered looking at the Scala Futures/Promises library http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/core/futures.html? The latter offers a cleanly designed, composable API for futures; from my experience, definitely worth it when you are dealing a lot with asynchronous code.

Comment: > "// should never happen, Servlet's thread shouldn't be interrupted"
This is a wrong assumption. You can also add Thread.currentThread().interrupt(); so next sleep()/wait() will not pause.

+1 for @BorisTreukhov

Comment: @LuigiR.Viggiano Thanks. If I'm not interrupting my servlet, who else will?

Comment: The container on shutdown for example.

Answer (score 3):

As [suggested in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14026513/is-checking-future-state-by-get0-timeunit-microseconds-a-good-idea#comment19373190_14026513), just use [`Future.isDone`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Future.html#isDone()) to check the run status. However you still need to call `get()` to determine if it completed successfully, checking for exceptions.

Comment: That's why I thought to only use exception, instead of using hybrid approach. Is there anything wrong with using exceptions?

Comment: It's just generally considered bad form to use exceptions to control program flow when there is an alternative in the API.

Comment: @HBase ExecutionException is thrown by get() but it's not supposed to be a tool to control the program flow, it's for the unchecked exceptions - i.e. to handle unexpected situations, as for isDone() and isCancelled() - it's not unexpected situation to poll the state to see if the task is done or cancelled. The API is perfectly designed.

Comment: @BorisTreukhov exception is an unexpected situation in the task, exception in a child task is NOT unexpected situation for the task manager. And I see no point with mixing exceptions and `if`s, if I already need an exception. It would make the code more complex.

Comment: As @Duncan mentioned in his comment exceptions are not a tool to control the program flow. Another important concern is the performance - stack unwinding and exception handling is just unacceptable for a high performance API which java concurrent aims to be.

Comment: @BorisTreukhov but as I mentioned earlier, I can't escape that. I want to find out if an exception has occurred in the future, so one exception or three exception don't really matter.

Comment: Then something is wrong with the code encapsulated in FutureTasks - if the result is negative, they should report this in the returning response, not by throwing exceptions. Polling the futures with `isDone()` and `isCancelled()` seems to more natural(and efficient). As for one or three - it matters: one case is an ExecutionException that occured because of an accidental network error(say 20 times per month) another - when your code will throw and catch millions of exceptions just to do what `isDone()` already does.

Comment: P.S. I'm not a fan of premature optimizations - but sometimes every context switch counts, and the throw-catch approach does not seem to bring any benefits.

Comment: @BorisTreukhov (1) in order to get the returning result, I need a get, (2) my code will not throw and catch exceptions, since there would usually be no exception when calling get.

Comment: @HBase if you *your code* is using `get()` with the zero timeout specified instead of `isCancelled`, of course it *will* throw and catch a lot of exceptions

Comment: @BorisTreukhov yeah, but that would be only when polling for the state, which by definition shouldn't happen a lot. And in the millionth time, this is not INSTEAD of `isCancell`ed, I have to do that since I don't have `isException`.